# nmap raw packet privileges not working ("operation not permitted", even as root)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ethernet, nmap

Why am I getting the "operation not permitted" with nmap - even when executed as root?

```
$ sudo nmap 192.168.1.2

Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-13 02:12 CST
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(5, packet, 44, 0, 192.168.1.2, 16) => Operation not permitted
Offending packet: TCP 192.168.1.1:53769 > 192.168.1.2:2099 S ttl=47 id=47294 iplen=44  seq=2821662280 win=1024 <mss 1460>
...
Omitting future Sendto error messages now that 10 have been shown.  Use -d2 if you really want to see them.
```

This is not an iptables issue - my OUTPUT chain is wide open:

```
$ sudo iptables -L OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now, I do have a few different interfaces here, with VLANs and a bridge.  This is working on some interfaces and not others:

- `br0`: Bridge over `eth0` (untagged) and `vbox0` (using VirtualBox), has IP `192.168.1.1` -> Not working (above).

  - For kicks, removing `vbox0` from the bridge doesn't fix anything.
- `eth0.2`: VLAN 2, with IP `192.168.2.1`.  Executing nmap on addresses in this subnet works as expected -> working.

  - This seems significant, as this goes out the same physical NIC as `eth0` (above).
- `vbox1`: Has IP `192.16.3.1`.  Executing nmap on addresses in this subnet works as expected -> working.

This is a physical workstation - not being operated under any virtualization or container that might impose additional restrictions here.

Bridge:

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0015171970fc       no              eth0
                                                        vbox0
```

Granted, I can work-around this by using a less-privileged TCP connect scan (`-sT`) rather than the default TCP SYN scan (`-sS`) - but this doesn't explain why this is happening.

Are there any known limitations here with the Ethernet bridging, or anything else I should be looking at?

**Edits (2017-01-14):**

- Attempting to replicate in a clean VM (2 vCPU on an i7 physical system).  Even after setting up the bridge, unable to reproduce.
- Disabling all Ethernet offloading options (using ethtool) does nothing to help.
- Running the latest compiled-from-source Nmap 7.40 does nothing to help.
- **This appears to be a kernel issue?** http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2016/q4/131 .  Not sure why I couldn't reproduce on the VM, despite the same versions.  Possibly also hardware/driver-specific...

  - This looks to be an issue with the `iptable_nat` module in the current 4.8.x kernels: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1402695
- The scan still runs.  This only seems to impact the start of the scan - for which I remain concerned as I may be missing results.

  - It says that all messages after the first 10 have been omitted.  However, even after repeating with the `-d2` as prompted, I still see only 10.  (Could be a bug in itself, however.)
  - If I repeat the scan for a given port as listed (e.g. with `-p 2099` for the example shown above), it scans successfully for that port - so it isn't as if certain ports are blocked.
- **Running with `--max-parallelism=1` drastically reduces the occurrence.**

  - Setting to 50 doesn't seem to help.
  - Setting to 30 seems to work about half the time for a single host - but still eventually starts failing for a subnet scan.
  - Progressively lower values lengthen the time it takes into a subnet scan for any failures to be observed - but even using 1 fails eventually.
  - This does not appear to be a parallelism issue within nmap itself.  Running multiple concurrent nmap scans with `parallel` and `--max-parallelism=1` re-increases the occurrence of the issue.

Host info:  Ubuntu 16.10, kernel 4.8.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu.  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600S, 32 GB RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be an issue with the `iptable_nat` module in the current 4.8.x Linux kernels (< 4.8.16), as per https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1402695.

The 4.9 kernel includes a "real" fix - but as for Ubuntu, I am guessing we'll have to wait for Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) to see this officially.  (4.9 will be included there, as per the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes#Linux_kernel_4.9)).

As for Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak), it looks like a fixed 4.8.16 kernel is pending release per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1654584, which includes the following fixes:

> Revert "netfilter: nat: convert nat bysrc hash to rhashtable"
>   
>   Revert "netfilter: move nat hlist_head to nf_conn"

I updated to this kernel using http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.16/ and the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds.  (I trust it will be further upgraded as usual as additional updates follow.)  This not only resolved my issue, but resulted in a massive scanning performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down! I had lost track of it, but we (Nmap) did have users reporting it back in February. Always nice when a bug turns out to be someone else's problem and they fix it :)